# Create a page using two views drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

i have two views

**view A**

```
Content type 1

content type 2
content type 3
```

**View B**

```
Content type 4
content type 5
```

And I want a page like

View A                                 View B

```
Content type 1                       Content type 

content type 2                       Content type 5
content type 3
```

I did the following i have select view A and add View B but i got a blank page.is it possible using drupal 8?please help me

i created this using grid view but when i add new content type view will change.Can i set auto generated column false in drupal?Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to create two block views and place the blocks on a page

maybe something like this helps:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya8_koKb4S0